# Problems using krpano locally in Android and iOS

Tags: java, android, ios, eclipse

I have created several panoramas with krpano and I am developing a mobile app (iOS + Android) which shows them.

Everything works fine if I access the krpano files online from my server, but I cannot make it work when I include the files as app resources and try to access them locally. The errors I find are the following:

- iOS app: black screen.
- Android app: black screen and an error message: “FATAL ERROR: my_pano.xml - loading failed (network error: a network error occurred).

I have made lots of tests: only krpano files fail to load; other local html + js files are loaded locally without problems.

What can be preventing krpano files to load locally?

In Android, I am using a WebView object to load the pano, and from a online url it works properly, but not locally.

This is my code on Android:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

        //para no salir de mi webview al pinchar
        //y cargar una pantalla SPLASH mientras carga la web
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
        {               
        });


        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true); //activa javascript
        webSettings.setBlockNetworkLoads(false); //para que no de bloqueos de red
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true); //recomiendan poner tb esto


        //no está funcionando la carga de la web desde local
        myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/asuncion.html");
        // myWebView.loadUrl("http://coolab.umh.es/360/alcudia/alcudia.html"); 


    }
```

I get the following error:
[image: error in android app]

However I can see the pano from Eclipse:

[image: eclipse screenshot]

Any suggestion is really welcome!!

Comment: For android you may try [MozillaView](https://github.com/infil00p/MozillaView) instead of `WebView` to overcome WebView's limitations.

Comment: Anything come of this?

Answer (score 1):

In addiction to what *ilovebali* said, you could try **CrossWalk** (an alternative to the Android default webview), which in my case revelead itself to be a pretty good solution for this kind of things.

Here's a sample of code that shows what you asked:

```
    xWalkView = (XWalkView) this.findViewById(R.id.your_xwalk_webview);
    xWalkView.load(filePath, null);

    XWalkPreferences.setValue(XWalkPreferences.REMOTE_DEBUGGING, true);
    XWalkPreferences.setValue(XWalkPreferences.ALLOW_UNIVERSAL_ACCESS_FROM_FILE, true);
    XWalkPreferences.setValue(XWalkPreferences.JAVASCRIPT_CAN_OPEN_WINDOW, true);
```

Have a look at this link if need more infos: https://diego.org/2015/01/07/embedding-crosswalk-in-android-studio/

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem lies with the native android browser that is probably used by WebView.
Neither the native android browser nor chrome would let a website access xml files locally.

I didn't try to encapsulate the the krpano into a WebView. But just copied the files onto the device and tried to open it with the native browser. I hunted down the error to this.

The only way I was able to view the krpano panorama on an Android device was by installing the Firefox or Dolphin browser and viewing the local page in that browser.

Hope this helps at least.

Answer (score 0):

Try add this code into you activity, I used code bellow to handle CORS (cross origin request)

```
  myWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
  myWebView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
  myWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
  myWebView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
```

Hope that help...

Answer (score 0):

You can use KRPano or PanaromaGl Library to achieve the same.

checkout below link:

http://krpano.com/

https://github.com/anispy211/PanaromaGL

Comment: Please avoid link only answers. Refer to the help section for details.